# Natural Language Processing - Truecaser classifier

Tags: nlp, classification

Please suggest a good machine learning classifier for truecasing of dataset.
Also, Is it possible to specify out own rules/features for truecasing in such a classifier? Thanks for all your suggestions.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I implemented a version of a truecaser in Python. It can be trained for any language when you provide enough data (i.e. correctly cased sentences).

For English, it achieves an accuracy of 98.38% on sample sentences from Wikipedia. A pre-trained model for English is provided.

You can find it here:
https://github.com/nreimers/truecaser

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. From [How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this whitepaper.

http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~llita/papers/lita.truecasing-acl2003.pdf

They report 98% of accuracy.

Comment: Do you know where the implementation can be found?